# Notepad++ extract fields from line regardless of order

Tags: notepad++, regex

Noob with regular expressions. Each line in my text file has several fields, of which I want to extract two: the first and a second that isn't always in the same place. What I have:

```
"Silicone Rubber" envdata="1" matid="232" failurecriteria="4"
"S-Glass Fiber" matid="62" failurecriteria="4" envdata="1"
```

What I want:

```
"Silicone Rubber" matid="232"
"S-Glass Fiber" matid="62"
```

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: Is the first field to select always at the begining of a line?

Comment: Yes, always; only the second field moves around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for example the following:

Find what: `^("[\w \-\(\)]*").*( matid="\d*").*`
Replace with: `\1\2`

Comment: Thanks, works but seems to be defeated by parens in the first field which I didn't notice before. Example: "POLYURETHANE (11671)" envdata="0" matid="229" failurecriteria="4" is not affected (want "POLYURETHANE (11671)" matid="229"). Any suggestions?

Comment: No problem : just add (escaped) parenthesis to the search, as above.

Comment: Following your suggestion I had to add a few more escaped chars: ^("[\w \-\(\)\,\.\%\*\;\-\/]*").*( matid="\d*").* but now it works perfectly. Many many thanks!